# intersect method seems not working here

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a snippet to exclude duplicated cells. So if there is a cell in column 4 that starts with 0-9 (all in text format) and does not appear in column 8, I would like to add the cell value to a string variable. But it seems the intersect method always return Nothing here...any idea?

```
Sub getAddNum()

addnum = ""

Set rng1 = Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Set rng2 = Columns(8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

For Each currentcell In rng1
    cellValue = CStr(currentcell.Value)
    If InStr("0123456789", CStr(Left(cellValue, 1))) And Intersect(currentcell, rng2)        Is Nothing Then
    addnum = addnum & CStr(currentcell.Value) & ", "
End If
Next 

Range("I9").Value = addnum

End Sub
```

Comment: it is working. But as you can see, you are iterating cells in `Columns(4)` which is logically not an `intersect` of `Columns(8)`. `Intersect` evaluates if a `Range Object` is in fact within another `Range Object`. It does not evaluate the `Value` of the cells. You may use `Application.Match` combined with `IsError` as second condition.

Comment: I tried the Match + isError but got an error msg: unable to get the property of the worksheetfunction class...how can I get it right?

Comment: see my post. It should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented, re-write your code like this:

```
Sub getAddNum()

Dim addnum As String, cellValue As String
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, currentcell As Range

addnum = ""

Set rng1 = Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Set rng2 = Columns(8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

For Each currentcell In rng1
    cellValue = CStr(currentcell.Value)
    If Left(cellValue, 1) Like "[0-9]" And IsError(Application.Match(cellvalue,rng2,0)) Then
    addnum = addnum & CStr(currentcell.Value) & ", "
End If
Next 

Range("I9").Value = addnum

End Sub
```

Not Tested, but I think you can get the logic.
Hope this somehow helps.